# Adicionar valores em DIV

Tags: javascript

Olá

Eu tenho 3 inputs, eu gostaria que ao digitar algo no input 1, seja inserido o conteudo em uma div chamada resultado, e ao digitar no input 2 seja inserido na div resultado e assim por diante, sem substituir o valor anterior em javascript.

Exemplo:

Input 1 - Valor: 10

Input 2 - Valor: 5

Input 3 - Valor: 12

Resultado na DIV: 10, 5, 12

Obrigado

Comment: Você está usando algum framework JS ou é javascript puro?

Comment: Javascript puro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passos:

- 1. Percorra cada `input` e adicione seu `value` em um *array*, caso ele não esteja vazio
- 2. Junte cada item do array com um ", ";
- 3. Escreva o resultado na div
- 4. Coloque tudo em uma função e a execute com o evento de `keyup` nos `inputs`

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.concatenate');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

function fillDiv() { 
  var result = [];
  [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input, i) { // percorrendo inputs
    if (input.value != "") { // verificando se está vazio
      result.push(input.value); // adicionando ao input
    };
  });
  div.innerHTML = result.join(', ') // juntando com o ", " e escrevendo o resultado na div
};

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input, i) { // adicionando a função ao evento key de cada input
  input.addEventListener('keyup', fillDiv);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="concatenate">
<br>
<input type="text" class="concatenate">
<br>
<input type="text" class="concatenate">
<br>
<input type="text" class="concatenate">
<br>
<input type="text" class="concatenate">
<br>
<br>Resultado:

<div></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas é quase isso que eu preciso, eu preciso que ao clicar no input pega o valor e joga na div;

Comment: @abduzeedo, acho que pelo que está escrito na pergunta, isso está servindo.

Comment: ok, Como ficaria para pegar o valor ao clicar ?

Comment: @abduzeedo, coloque ao invés de "keyup", "click"